# Docker-compose volume key: what protocol is used behind

Tags: docker

I am not sure if this is a right question to ask. In the tutorial of Docker compose, https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/#step-5-edit-the-compose-file-to-add-a-bind-mount, there is a volume key in the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

And according to the tutorial, the volume key mounts the local file to the remote, and therefore we can change the code on the fly without restarting the Docker. My question is what internet protocol is used behind to transfer the updated code file.

Furthermore, I guess there would be more framework having this feature. What are the common protocols behind and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial doesn't say "the volume key mounts the local file to the remote".  It says:

> ...in your project directory to add a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) for the web service:
>   [...]
>   The new volumes key mounts the project directory (current directory) on the host to /code inside the container, allowing you to modify the code on the fly, without having to rebuild the image.

If you click on the [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) link, it will take you to
documentation that should answer all of your questions.

Briefly, a bind mount is way of making one directory on your system
appear in another location.  For example, if I were run:

```
mkdir /tmp/newetc
mount -o bind /etc /tmp/newetc
```

Then running `ls /tmp/newetc` would show the same contents as `/etc`.
Docker uses this feature to expose host directories inside your
containers.

A bind mount only works on the same host; it cannot be used to expose
files on your local system to a remote system.  It is a kernel feature and there are no internet protocols involved.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I equated the 'host' here to all the potential host machines.

Comment: That same tutorial tells the person who follows along, that a ```bind mount``` will be added. But then proceeds by doing this with a ```Volumes``` mount. Which is completely different from a ```bind mount```. So in fact, there is no ```bind mount``` added at all.

Comment: @RobWaa Sorry, I'm not following that comment. The documentation at https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/ discusses the use of bind mount both via the `-v` flag as well as via `--mount`. It certainly prefers the `--mount` syntax because that is more explicit.

Comment: @larsks `Volumes:` w/o explanation about being able to specify `type` etc, can lead to the false assumption: by default only bind mounts will be created. The Redis container, w/o `Volumes:` has a volume mount. :)


```docker container ls -a```
```9d5a27b213c5 (testproj_web_1)```
```0aec44a12541 (testproj_redis_1)```

Comment: ```docker inspect 9d5a27b213c5```



```
"Mounts": [
  {
    "Type": "bind",
    "Source": "/home/bobbybabes/dev/mount-type-test",
    "Destination": "/code",
    "Mode": "rw",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": "rprivate"
  }
],
```

Comment: `docker inspect 0aec44a12541`

```
"Mounts": [
  {
    "Type": "volume",
    "Name": "1e4c79c594f77920854cc126e5f467bc87653930c763534960a3d0d2ba417241",
    "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/1e4c79c594f77920854cc126e5f467bc87653930c763534960a3d0d2ba417241/_data",
    "Destination": "/data",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Mode": "",
    "RW": true,
    "Propagation": ""
  }
],
```

Comment: Yes, the configuration shown in the question creates a bind mount: that is well documented in the `docker-compose` documentation. Thank you for the examples of how to verify that; I'm sure someone will find that useful. Still not sure what all these comments are about.